# Не получается загрузить ключ RSA

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, rsa

Я сохранил ключ в файле с расширением `.PEM` и пытаюсь его загрузить, но при попытке это сделать появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crypto_log.py", line 110, in app_key_task
    decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), key_priv)
  File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Как это решить?

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from oge import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import rsa

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

import base64
import os


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.04.75")

        #        self.key_priv = None
        #        self.pub_key = None
        self.key_pub, self.key_priv = rsa.newkeys(512)  # !!! +++

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.app_key_task)

    def app_key_task(self):
        if not os.path.exists('key_pub.pem'):
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Не обнаружен "key_pub.pem"')
            return

        with open('key_pub.pem', "rb") as f:
            _key_pub = f.read()

        key_pub = self.key_pub.load_pkcs1(_key_pub)

        self.information()

    def time(self):
        beg = datetime.strptime(str('01:59:59'), '%H:%M:%S')
        end = datetime.strptime(str('00:00:00'), '%H:%M:%S')
        step = timedelta(seconds=1)
        while beg != end:
            beg = beg - step
            print(str(beg).split()[1])
            self.lable_55.setText(str(beg).split()[1])
            time.sleep(1)

    def information(self):
        self.dd_mm_yy = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.region = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.code_eo = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        self.number_class = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        self.letter_class = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.code_location_event = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.number_auditorium = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.number_option = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.code_subject = self.lineEdit_17.text()
        self.item_name = self.lineEdit_18.text()
        self.number_kim = self.lineEdit_19.text()

        self.surname = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.name = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.patronymic = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.ser_passport = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_passport = self.lineEdit_4.text()

        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit_20.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_22.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_21.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_23.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_24.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_25.text()
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_26.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_27.text()
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_28.text()
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_29.text()
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_30.text()
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_31.text()

        self.crypto_information()

    def crypto_information(self):
        self.dd_mm_yy_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.dd_mm_yy.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.region_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.region.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.code_eo_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.code_eo.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_class_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_class.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.letter_class_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.letter_class.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.code_location_event_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.code_location_event.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_auditorium_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_auditorium.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_option_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_option.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.code_subject_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.code_subject.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.item_name_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.item_name.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_kim_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_kim.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.surname_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.surname.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.name_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.name.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.patronymic_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.patronymic.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.ser_passport_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.ser_passport.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_passport_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_passport.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.load_information()

    #
    def load_information(self):
        k = [self.dd_mm_yy_crypto, self.region_crypto, self.code_eo_crypto, self.number_class_crypto,
             self.letter_class_crypto,
             self.code_location_event_crypto, self.number_auditorium_crypto, self.number_option_crypto,
             self.code_subject_crypto,
             self.item_name_crypto, self.number_kim_crypto, self.surname_crypto, self.name_crypto,
             self.patronymic_crypto,
             self.ser_passport_crypto, self.number_passport_crypto, self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto,
             self.number_3_crypto,
             self.number_4_crypto, self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto,
             self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto]

        with open("TEST.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in k))

    def key_date(self):
        self.key = self.dialog.lineEdit.text()

        self.key_check()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(675, 598)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralWidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addRow('', self.label)

        for i in range(6):
            name = f"lineEdit_{i + 1}"
            lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Введите что-нибудь...")
            lineEdit.setObjectName(name)
            self.layout.addRow(name, lineEdit)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Проверить заполнение lineEdits')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.layout.addRow('', self.pushButton)

    def button_clicked(self):
        lineEdits = self.findChildren(QLineEdit)
        text = ''
        for lineEdit in lineEdits:
            if not lineEdit.text():
                print(f'Заполните {lineEdit.objectName()}')
                text = f'{text}Заполните {lineEdit.objectName()}\n'
        if text:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', text)
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Информация', 'Все lineEdits заполнены.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(300, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Интерфейс: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mXfYQKxhX2k2wxNmUs896TTDOn1q5foM/view?usp=sharing

**Update**:

Для получение данной ошибки необходимо пролистать вниз интерфейса и нажать на кнопку **"Завершить работу"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не пишите какие надо выполнить действия чтобы получить ошибку?

Пока, из того что я вижу, мне не нравится две строк:

```
    self.key_priv = None
    self.pub_key = None
```

попробуйте заменить их на:

```
    self.key_pub, self.key_priv = rsa.newkeys(512)
```

---

**Update**

> это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Я хочу загрузить публичный и приватный ключ для шифрование данных, что бы позже через другую программу (была представлена в прошлом вопросе) их расшифровывать. –
>
> я учёл ваше замечание и исправил программу, но это не помогло, ключи просто генерировались, а не загпужались из файлов.

Вы точно тестируетесь на коде, который вы предоставили как пример? 
Вот смотрите, я внес изменение, о которых писал выше и все работает.

Файлы **key_priv.pem** и **1111.txt** у меня остались после запуска примера, который я вам предоставил как ответ на предыдущий вопрос.

Если у вас возникают другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from oge import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import rsa

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

import base64
import os

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.04.75")

#        self.key_priv = None
#        self.pub_key = None
        self.key_pub, self.key_priv = rsa.newkeys(512)                             # !!! +++ 
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.app_key_task)

    def app_key_task(self):
        if not os.path.exists('key_priv.pem'):
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Не обнаружен "key_priv.pem"')
            return

        with open('key_priv.pem', "rb") as f:
            _key_priv = f.read()

        key_priv = self.key_priv.load_pkcs1(_key_priv)
        print(f'\n{key_priv}\n') #

        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ".", "*.txt")
        if not directory_file:
            return
        with open(directory_file, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), key_priv)
            print(decrypted.decode('utf8'))
        print(f'\n -=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- \n')

        print(f'\n{type(self.key_pub)} = \n{self.key_pub}')    # <class 'rsa.key.PublicKey'>
        print(f'\n{type(self.key_priv)} = \n{self.key_priv}')  # <class 'rsa.key.PrivateKey'>

        self.information()

    def time(self):
        beg = datetime.strptime(str('01:59:59'), '%H:%M:%S')
        end = datetime.strptime(str('00:00:00'), '%H:%M:%S')
        step = timedelta(seconds=1)
        while beg != end:
            beg = beg - step
            print(str(beg).split()[1])
            self.lable_55.setText(str(beg).split()[1])
            time.sleep(1)


    def information(self):
        self.dd_mm_yy = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.region = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.code_eo = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        self.number_class = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        self.letter_class = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.code_location_event = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.number_auditorium = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.number_option = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.code_subject = self.lineEdit_17.text()
        self.item_name = self.lineEdit_18.text()
        self.number_kim = self.lineEdit_19.text()

        self.surname = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.name = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.patronymic = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.ser_passport = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_passport = self.lineEdit_4.text()

        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit_20.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_22.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_21.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_23.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_24.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_25.text()
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_26.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_27.text()
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_28.text()
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_29.text()
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_30.text()
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_31.text()

        self.crypto_information()

    def crypto_information(self):
        self.dd_mm_yy_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.dd_mm_yy.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.region_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.region.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.code_eo_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.code_eo.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_class_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_class.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.letter_class_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.letter_class.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.code_location_event_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.code_location_event.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_auditorium_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_auditorium.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_option_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_option.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.code_subject_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.code_subject.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.item_name_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.item_name.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_kim_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_kim.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.surname_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.surname.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.name_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.name.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.patronymic_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.patronymic.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.ser_passport_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.ser_passport.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_passport_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_passport.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.load_information()
    #
    def load_information(self):
        k = [self.dd_mm_yy_crypto, self.region_crypto, self.code_eo_crypto, self.number_class_crypto, self.letter_class_crypto,
             self.code_location_event_crypto, self.number_auditorium_crypto, self.number_option_crypto, self.code_subject_crypto,
             self.item_name_crypto, self.number_kim_crypto, self.surname_crypto, self.name_crypto, self.patronymic_crypto,
             self.ser_passport_crypto, self.number_passport_crypto, self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto,
             self.number_4_crypto, self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto]

        with open("TEST.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in k))


    def key_date(self):
        self.key = self.dialog.lineEdit.text()

        self.key_check()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(675, 598)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    
    





from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addRow('', self.label)  
        
        for i in range(6):
            name = f"lineEdit_{i+1}"
            lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Введите что-нибудь...")
            lineEdit.setObjectName(name)
            self.layout.addRow(name, lineEdit)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Проверить заполнение lineEdits')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.layout.addRow('', self.pushButton)
        
    def button_clicked(self):
        lineEdits =  self.findChildren(QLineEdit)
        text = ''
        for lineEdit in lineEdits:
            if not lineEdit.text():
                print(f'Заполните {lineEdit.objectName()}')
                text = f'{text}Заполните {lineEdit.objectName()}\n'
        if text:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', text)
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Информация', 'Все lineEdits заполнены.')        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(300, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Я хочу загрузить публичный и приватный ключ для шифрование данных, что бы позже через другую программу (была представлена в прошлом вопросе) их расшифровывать.

Comment: @Settings вы попробовали сделать то что я вам предложил? Если да, то что у вас получилось, если нет, то почему не попробовали?

Comment: я учёл ваше замечание и исправил программу, но это не помогло, ключи просто генерировались, а не загпужались из файлов.

Comment: смотрите, в программе представленной мною как вопрос выполняется только шифрование данных с помощью ключей, а в программе которую я представлял ранее эти данные расшифровываются и сравниваются с правильными. Представленный вами пример шифрует данные, но открыть их в прошлой программе нельзя.

Comment: @Settings я вас не понимаю, читаем `key_priv.pem` и достаем `_key_priv` - это секретный ключ. Далее читаем файл `1111.txt`, который содержит зашифрованную когда-то информацию - это объект `lines`.  Далее построчно расшифровываем данные `line` с использованием загруженного ключа `key_priv`. Просто запустите мой пример, все работает как надо.

Comment: так смотрите файл 1111.txt вы создали в предыдущей программе, а как я писал ранее в этой программе (которую я прикрепил сейчас) вы создаете файл и шифруете его, а расшифровку проводите в программе из предыдущего вопроса.

Comment: Другими словами в данной программе нет расшифровки, только шифровка данных по ключу созданному в предыдущей программе.

Comment: @Settings вы все перепутали, для шифрования данных используются публичные ключи из файла `key_pub.pem` , смотрите метод `information()` в моем ответе на предыдущий ваш вопрос.

Comment: разобрался, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Settings пожалуйста.